# Set clicked child component active while all of its siblings inactive?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Sorry if the phrasing of my question is unclear. I'm new to React and making an app with three different screens/pages. There should be a footer that follows the state of the payment process thanks to 3 boxes. The box that is being selected should show up in another color (here I've used a solid blue border).

[image: Three boxes, the first one being selected]

When clicking on another box (box 3 for example), I would like the third box to be selected and the other two boxes to be unselected. In order to achieve this, I've set up a state.active in the child element. If the state is active, then a different style is applied to the element (the blue border).

I have two components, "ProgressBar" being the parent, and "ProgressElement" being the child. Here is what the code looks like :

```
class ProgressElement extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selected: false
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.props.eleType === "pattern") {
            this.setState({selected: true})
        }
    }

    handleClick() {
        if (!this.state.selected) {
            this.setState({selected: true})
        }
        if (this.state.selected) {
            this.setState({selected: false})
        }
    }


    render() {
        let eleNumber = NaN
        if (this.props.eleType === "pattern") {
            eleNumber = 1;
            this.state.selected === true;
        }
        if (this.props.eleType === "gift") {
            eleNumber = 2;
        }
        if (this.props.eleType === "personal") {
            eleNumber = 3;
        }

        if (this.state.selected) {
            return <div className="square-box selected"
                        onClick={this.handleClick}>{eleNumber}</div>
        } else {
            return <div className="square-box"
                        onClick={this.handleClick}>{eleNumber}</div>
        }

    }

}

class ProgressBar extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div className="d-flex custom-progress-bar">
            <ProgressElement eleType="pattern"/>
            <ProgressElement eleType="gift"/>
            <ProgressElement eleType="personal"/>
        </div>
    }
}
```

It's working fine, but my only problem is that I don't know how to make the other boxes unselected. For that, I would need the other sibling elements to be aware of the state of the other ones. I've thought of two ways to do this but have been unable to make one of these work so far :

- first one would be to pass informations about the state of the child to the parent, but I think that goes against the principle of unidirectional data flow
- second one would be to put the "active" state in the parent instead of the child, but I'm not sure how to keep tracks of all child like this. I've tried to do it with an array but didn't succeed so far.

Could anyone help me with this ? I know this is probably basic stuff but I'm having a hard time with React. Thanks for reading me and thanks in advance.

Comment: I can help you if you can make a [CodeSandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-montalcini-ulyuv) for same

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov comment is the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep track of currently active child within the parent component and pass it down as a prop:

```js
const { Component } = React,
      { render } = ReactDOM,
      rootNode = document.getElementById('root')
      
class ProgressElement extends React.Component {
   handleClick = eleType => this.props.onSetActive(eleType)

   render(){  
      return (
        <div 
          className={this.props.eleType === this.props.activeEleType && 'active'}
          onClick={() => this.handleClick(this.props.eleType)}
        >
          {this.props.eleType}
        </div>
      )
   }
}

class ProgressBar extends React.Component {
    state = {activeEleType: null}
    onSetActive = activeEleType => this.setState({
      activeEleType
    })
    
    render() {
        return (
          <div className="progress-bar">
            {
              ['pattern', 'gift', 'personal'].map(key => (
                <ProgressElement 
                  activeEleType={this.state.activeEleType}
                  eleType={key}
                  key={key}
                  onSetActive={this.onSetActive}
                />
              ))
            }
          </div>
        )
    }
}

render (
  <ProgressBar />,
  rootNode
)
```

```css
.progress-bar {
  display: flex;
}

.progress-bar>div {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background: grey;
   color: #fff;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   margin: 10px;
   cursor: pointer;
}

.progress-bar>div.active {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working perfectly. There are a few things I'm not grasping perfectly yet so I'm going to read this again a few times, but thanks again for your answer ! I'm glad.

Answer (score 1):

Try and apply this, I did not test the code myself so make sure that you apply the logic to your code (I'm rusted with classes)

```
 class ProgressElement extends React.Component {

    render() {

        if (this.props.eleType === this.props.selected) {
            return <div className="square-box selected"
            onClick={this.props.act({selectedValue:""})}>{this.props.eleType}</div>
        } else {
            return <div className="square-box"
                        onClick={this.props.act({selectedValue:this.props.eleType})}>{this.props.eleType}</div>
        }

    }

}

class ProgressBar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedValue: ""
        }
    }
    updateSelected = (selected) => {
        this.setState(selected);
    }


    render() {
        return <div className="d-flex custom-progress-bar">
            <ProgressElement eleType="pattern" act={this.updateSelected} selected={this.state.selectedValue}/>
            <ProgressElement eleType="gift" act={this.updateSelected} selected={this.state.selectedValue}/>
            <ProgressElement eleType="personal" act={this.updateSelected} selected={this.state.selectedValue}/>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I've tried running it but I'm getting a "Uncaught TypeError: this.updater is undefined". I think it's coming from the this.setState. Shouldn't it receive an argument ?